# Redirect to command prompt without creating a child process. Batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

As far as I am concerned (after digging a bit on the topic) that in order to redirect a user to a command prompt after the batch file completed execution it is a common practice to simply put "cmd /k" at the very end of the batch file.

However, the history of the user input is lost since it is not passed on to a child process, which is created by "cmd /k". I was wondering if there is another way of bringing up command prompt after the batch file finished working?

Just so we are on the same page, I double click the batch file. I know that if I call it from the open terminal I won't be having this problem. However, I am curious how to circumvent that in the case I mentioned. Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: cmd /k keeps the window open cmd /c closes it. And it is not at the end, it is the way the cmd window is started. To do debugging it is essential to start the batch from the console. Albeit when using setlocal (which is required when needing delayed expansion) the variables are lost when the batch stops. You have to toggle echo then and maybe echo important variables.

Comment: Put this in the last line: `start /B cmd`

Comment: @Aacini Yes, that works exactly as I wanted it to work. No extra processes are created. If you like, you can post it as an answer so I could mark it as answered.

Comment: @LotPings That's good supplementary information to understanding the process, thank you.